# Sweating due to coffee intake

Tags: health, caffeine

I sweat a lot. I have tried so many methods to combat sweating but none of it worked. Antiperspirants and other home remedies didn't work at all. I don't have enough money to go for botox or other expensive treatments as I'm saving it for something else.

I am a coffee addict. I can't function without at least 5 cups of coffee daily. Is it true that coffee consumption will result in sweating? If yes, how can I reduce my coffee intake? (I'm not a fan of decaf).

Comment: Anti-perspirants won't help. You'll have to find other ways to mitigate your over heating.

Comment: Not directly related to coffee, but I've noticed that my BO is worse when I'm not exercising (taking an extended break now, for example). If the problem is more BO than sweat, that might help.

Comment: out of curiosity what kind of coffee do you drink? ps sweating a lot is not necessarily bad, consult a doctor it might not be related to caffeine intake

Answer (score 2):

Coffee can cause some sweating when consumed in very high dosages. Your core temperature increases because of central nervous system activation and your body tries to regulate temperature. However 5 cups a day don't seem close to an overdose unless your caffeine tolerance is very low and studies have shown that normal dosages of caffeine intake don't alter core temperature or increase sweating to an extent where it would affect your hydration (see e.g. McLellan et. al 2016 for a Review). It still might be noticeable if you sweat a lot in general. I would just trial and error it by not drinking coffee for a few days. You might notice increased sweating for a day or two from withdrawal but that should pass after a couple of days. However these "health" websites have a lot of misinformation on them that are not scientifically supported.

References:

- McLellan, T. M., Caldwell, J. A., & Lieberman, H. R. (2016). A review of caffeine’s effects on cognitive, physical and occupational performance. Neuroscience & Biobehavioral Reviews, 71, 294-312.